# service worker registration fails-Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:1)

Tags: angular, firebase, service-worker

iam trying to integrate firbase cloud messaging to my angular app.

iam using latest version of firbase npm package

but my service worker registration fails and gives me above mentioned error

iam following the official firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

and my firbase-messaging-sw.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";
// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
const fcmConfig = {}; //my config object
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(fcmConfig);
// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here

  const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: "Background Message body.",
    tag: "notification-1",
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: "window",
      })
      .then(function (clientList) {
        console.log(event);
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          var client = clientList[i];
          if (
            client.url == event.notification.data.notification.click_action &&
            "focus" in client
          )
            return client.focus();
        }
        if (clients.openWindow)
          return clients.openWindow(
            event.notification.data.notification.click_action
          );
      })
  );
});
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {});
```

where i did wrong?
is my implementation is correct?

Answer (score 1):

i am also having similar error when i tried to import the like you did.

when i import like below iam not seeing above error in my console.

i reached this solution from Maria galvez answer to this question
[getMessaging failing - Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249364/getmessaging-failing-uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside)

```
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);
const urConfigObj = {}
firebase.initializeApp(urConfigObj);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: "Background Message body.",
    tag: "notification-1",
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: "window",
      })
      .then(function (clientList) {
        console.log(event);
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          var client = clientList[i];
          if (
            client.url == event.notification.data.notification.click_action &&
            "focus" in client
          )
            return client.focus();
        }
        if (clients.openWindow)
          return clients.openWindow(
            event.notification.data.notification.click_action
          );
      })
  );
});
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {});
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.but i have already installed firbase 9.14 npm package,if i again imported from this url will it cause more download size?

Comment: @sinan i don't know much about it. but this code cleaned the above error from my console.